# PhpStorm - integrate method braces style with PSR-2 point 4.4

Tags: phpstorm

How to enforce (in PhpStorm) method code style like [this](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#44-method-arguments):

```
class ClassName
{
    public function foo($arg1, &$arg2, $arg3 = [])
    {
        // method body
    }

    public function aVeryLongMethodName(
        ClassTypeHint $arg1,
        &$arg2,
        array $arg3 = []
    ) {
        // method body
    }
}
```

While having
*"Braces placement" => "In function declaration" => "Next line"*
brace `{` is falling under `)` in the `aVeryLongMethodName()` method case.

Comment: Use predefined PSR-1/2 style in IDE. There is `Set from...` clickable label on the top right side of the appropriate Settings screen. If you need to add such formatting to your already existing scheme ... then compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LazyOne mentioned in the comment, using predefined style is everything I need.

Option is available here:

[image]

and then: ***"Predefined style" => "PSR1/PSR2"***